# Getting coordinates of pixels inside QgsRasterBlock

Tags: raster, pyqgis

I am trying to implement a function that filters some points around a focus point in QGis, based on a raster map, and then does some distance calculations with the result. For this, I need to convert between geo-coordinates and raster layer point indices.

So, let's say `raster` is a `QgsRasterLayerObject`. I know I can get the data array like

```
provider = raster.dataProvider()

raster_extent = provider.extent()
raster_width = provider.xSize()
raster_height = provider.ySize()
no_data_value = provider.srcNoDataValue(1)

block = provider.block(1, raster_extent, raster_width,
            raster_height)
if block.isValid():
  for x in range(raster_width):
    for y in range(raster_height):
      value = block.value(x, y)
      if value != no_data_value:
        ...
```

I have read the code of [`QgsRasterDataProvider.identify`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/bd1b27087d94095318fbe8c9f17720b599007a42/src/core/raster/qgsrasterdataprovider.cpp#L246-L309) and it seems to me that there is only very simple arithmetic computation deriving the array index from the coordinates, which in Python looks like this.

```
extent = provider.extent()
xres = (extent.width()) / provider.xSize()
yres = (extent.height()) / provider.ySize()
col = int((location.x() - extent.xMinimum()) / xres)
row = int((location.y() - extent.yMinimum()) / yres)
value = block.value(col, row)
if value != no_data_value:
  ...
```

Are there any data providers of rectangular data for which this code would lead to wrong, but not obviously apparently wrong results, or can I use this and its obvious inverse in my function?

Comment: I [keep running into mistakes in my ordering of coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58642969/1274613), did I get it right this time?